# UISearchController misplaces UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using the UISearchController on a modal page to allow a user to search some data.  The page uses a table view controller design and the searchBar is in a tableViewCell.

When the user taps on the searchBar, the UISearchController animates the layout to slide the table header to the top of the page and moves the searchbar.  However it does not end up in the right place.  It does not move sufficiently up.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to help the UISearchController to position the searchBar correctly?

Before tapping the search bar (looks ok)
[image]

After tapping the search bar (search bar in wrong place)
[image]

Comment: Hi. You should add the searchBar in the tableHeader. Using him like tableCell is bad decision.

Comment: It is not an option from a UI perspective to use the tableHeader.  The search is only related to a portion of the table, not the entire table.  However, I agree with you that it looks like the designer of UISearchController only considered the case when the searchBar is in the table header.