# UISearchBar of UISearchController moves off screen when active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I need to have a `UISearchBar` **above** a `UITableView` (ie. the search bar is not part of the table view), and what I found is that when the search bar is activated, it moves off screen.

I did a fair bit of search and could not find a solution, there are ‘search bar off screen’ issues but they are adding search bar to table's header view and tweaking properties like `definesPresentationContext` fixed it.

My view hierarchy:

VC’s view
|— top view
       |— segmented control
       |— search bar
|— table view

Looks like UISearchController expects the search bar to be inside the table view, and always shifts the table view so that the search bar moves to the very top of screen.

Anyone having the same issue and found a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updates

After further testing I decided to just implement the UISearchBar delegate and stop using the UISearchController since I was just reusing my UICollectionView for the results. Found a [great guide on how three different methods](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Search-Bar-Guide) to implement the SearchBar.

### Edge Case #1

> TLDR
>
> **Enable clips to bounds on the containing view. Or if you have a collection view cell that has a user-generated content view, enable clips to bounds on that content view.**

**Details:**

An additional very important fact is that you may have the search bar embedded in a container view. This can cause issues if the container view does not have clips to bounds enabled. Other examples of this being a problem is the user-generated content views in UICollectionViewCells. Compare the setting on a UITableViewCell auto-generated content view to observe the difference.

> Summary
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
> bounds of the view. Declaration
>
> var clipsToBounds: Bool { get set } Discussion
>
> Setting this value to true causes **subviews to be clipped to the bounds**
> of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond
> the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value
> is false.

### Swift 4.x Solution

In my case, this was happening both inside a UICollectionView and inside of a UIStackView. I was able to keep my searchBar in place after noticing the following info in the searchBar quick help.

> Summary
>
> The search bar to install in your interface. Declaration
>
> var searchBar: UISearchBar { get } Discussion
>
> Before presenting your searchable content, **install the search bar in**
> **this property somewhere into your view controller’s interface**. The
> search bar becomes the starting point for searching your contents.
> Interactions with the search bar are handled automatically by the
> UISearchController object, which notifies the object in the
> searchResultsUpdater property whenever the search information changes.
> To use a custom subclass of UISearchBar, subclass UISearchController
> and implement this property to return your custom search bar.

After that I was able to resolve the issue successfully by doing the following:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var searchBar:UISearchBar!
```

Sometime later I assign the searchBar from the searchController to the searchBar in my UIViewController...

BTW - I embed my searchBar in a container UIView that has all the contraints I need to keep it in place.

```
func setupSearchController<T:UIViewController>(delegate vc:T) where T: UISearchResultsUpdating, T:UISearchBarDelegate {
    searchBar = searchController.searchBar //this is the key
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = vc
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search".localized()
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = vc
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchMenu.addSubview(searchBar) 
    //searchMenu is a constrained UIView in my hierarchy
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// Swift 5

// if you are using UISearch Controller then simply add line below to your
viewDidLoad() and it will fix the issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     // fixes the search moving to next screen when its active
     self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe putting searchBar inside tableView is not mandatory. I had same issue some time back. All you need to do is setting proper auto layout constraint. Adjust leading and trailing of searchView as align to leading and trailing of the tableView. Also release the margin property from constraints. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes if I use `UISearchBar` by itself, there's no issue at all, but if I use the search bar from the new `UISearchController`, it shows some weird animation and mis-position when the search bar's activated. Found another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611874/uisearchcontroller-misplaces-uisearchbar?rq=1 and the PO mentioned that "it looks like the designer of UISearchController only considered the case when the searchBar is in the table header."

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I've found the reason being that when the `UISearchBar` is activated, `UISearchController` removes it from your view and puts it on its own view with a table view for showing the results, since I use auto-layout for the search bar, by removing it, some of the constraints are screwed up. So my solution was to not use auto layout for the `UISearchBar` from `UISearchController`.

Comment: What did you do to place the Search Bar then?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use UISearchBar without an UISearchController, which I have found much easier for keeping UISearchBar within its initial bounds, here is the code template:

```
final class MyUIViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: Properties
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    ...

    // MARK: View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    }
}

extension MyUIVewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        ... // Your code filtering tableView dataSource goes here

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove **Search Display Controller** from scene elements as mentioned below in image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXkbg.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34326193)